# Is it possible to edit the deleted post

Tags: support, editing, deleted-questions

After a long period a post is deleted, is it still possible to edit the deleted post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [this FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222), it says

> Self-deleted posts can be viewed and undeleted by their original authors. However, self-deleted questions cannot be edited by their authors unless undeleted first. Self-deleted answers can be edited by the author without undeleting. Normally, if your deleted post is not self-deleted, you can't undelete it yourself (though you may be able to vote to undelete). An exception: if an answer is deleted from Low Quality review queue by "Recommend Deletion" votes, without three trusted users voting to delete, then it [can be undeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479) by the author.

This implies that if a post is not self-deleted, then it can be edited by its author. This allows a post that is deleted by others to be improved so that it can be undeleted. However, if the post was [deleted more than 60 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile), you must have a link to the post or have it marked as a favorite to be able to find it.

Comment: I did not now of that detail that one cannot edit self-deleted questions. Thanks for bringing it up. I will complete my answer.

Comment: If somebody deletes my answer, and I see what I did wrong and fix it, do they get notified, or do I have to wait and hope that someone sees it?

Comment: @TymonMieszkowski: when a closed (and I assume this applies to deleted posts, as well) post is edited, it is put on a review queue and will be considered for reopening. If that does not happen, in a day or so, you can try posting to [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, provided that

- you have the appropriate privilege.
- you have access to the post.
- the post was only deleted and not also locked (and is not a *self*-deleted question, see other answer).

If it is about your own post mainly the last point is relevant.

As locking is mainly reserved for offensive or spam content and you could just undo a self-deletion, you should mostly be fine (unless you lost trace of the post).

Comment: That being said, you should probably make a small sacrifice to the SE Gods, in request that your edit is successful. :-)