# Can I recycle deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, deleted-questions, unanswered-questions

### Context

I wanted to completely empty the list of questions I had deleted but I realized that it is not possible to delete them permanently (or at least... I didn't find it).

### Question

I was wondering if it was possible ("possible" in the sense that it does not go against the MSE rules) to "recycle" deleted questions by modifying their content and removing them from the list of deleted questions.

I specify that these questions do not have upvotes or downvotes and they only have 10-20 views because I deleted them almost immediately.

> As an acceptable answer, I would also like to know if there is a way to empty the list of deleted questions (that was the purpose).

Comment: From what you wrote, it seems that among [your deleted questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current) you have some that are no longer interesting to you.
It is not really a satisfactory solution (it requires some manual work), but you could create one list [among your saves](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info) specifically for this purpose and add those deleted questions you're still interested in - after that you have them in one place.
(Of course, after some more of your questions get deleted, you'll need to update the list again.)

Comment: In this context, it is worth reminding that one cannot edit a self-deleted question - so you would need to undelete them before starting editing. Some references: 
[Is it possible to edit the deleted post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20768),
[Why can I not edit a self-deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296101) and 
[Let me edit my own self-deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327788).

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the rules, but whatever they say, I wouldn't recommend doing this. There isn't much to gain, and there are two significant drawbacks:

- The question history will be clobbered with an unrelated question.
- The date of the question will not be correct (and users trying to help may not understand immediately why it's so).

Additionally, the deleted question gets some visibility. Normally, a deleted question is only visible by you, and people who have both enough reputation ([10k](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)) and the link to the question (impossible to find it otherwise, except maybe for moderators) - usually that's very few people.

If it's deleted, so be it. If you have another question, ask another question.

By the way, when you get to 10k rep, you can see your own deleted posts by searching `deleted:1`

---

For an answer, however, I think reusing a deleted answer does not harm much, if there were no votes. You may also decide to provide another answer and leave the deleted one: there may be reasons, such as keeping another approach for future correction. Then I'd recommend replacing the contents of the deleted one with a single line (30 dots for instance), so as to reduce the occupied space in the list - because it's visible even if it's deleted, once you get to 10k rep.

Comment: Probably it is worth adding a caveat that [searching with deleted:1](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted:1) only works for 10k+ users. See also: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, thanks! I thought it worked for lower rep, as it's one's own posts. Good to know. Corrected.