# Question regarding deleted questions whilst under a post ban.

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, post-ban

I wanted to ask if you could recycle deleted questions that the Bot has automatically deleted and repurpose them into new questions before voting to undelete **whilst under a post ban** in any Stack Exchange?.

It has been at least more than 9 months since my post ban and while I have accepted it (and tried to contribute to the site in other ways), I wondered if the above is possible.

This question ([Can I recycle deleted questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36155/can-i-recycle-deleted-questions)) is similar but it doesn't fully answer what I am looking for.

*Note 1: I am not looking to get around or finding ways to lift my post ban. It is not my intent and I am simply curious as to whether there is a definitive answer to my question.*

*Note 2: My post ban is on Mathematics Stack Exchange, so I leave the link to my profile so that people can look at it before they answer/reply.*
*MSE Profile Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/789034/yajat-shamji*

**Edit 1:** *I am not going to recycle the deleted questions - I have simply been curious for the last 9 months whether it is possible to do it or not as well as whether it breaches MSE policy.*

Comment: By recycling, do you mean editing the deleted post to ask a completely new question?

Comment: @ArcticChar, yes.

Comment: The answer at the post you linked should suffice here too. Please don't do this.

Comment: @KReiser, it doesn't fully answer my question in the sense that it doesn't consider the following: 1. When the Bot deletes the question and you repurpose it (and after it gets undeleted via votes), can this impact the question ban? 2. Is this a breach of MSE policy (this is what I meant by a definitive answer)?

Comment: Also, @KReiser, I am not going to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Please don't do that.

You say you're not trying to find ways to get around the post ban.  Whether it's your intent or not, this would be an example of getting around the post ban -- or might be viewed that way.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260066/781723, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333131/781723.

Comment: I probably should have added this (and will) to the question description: *I am not going to do it - I have simply been curious for the last 9 months whether it is possible to do it or not.*

Comment: Also, the second link has nearly answered the question. Only problem that needs addressing is: does it violate MSE policy?

Comment: Revision is not replacement. New questions go in new posts. Don't do it.

Comment: @YajatShamji, Why do you need to know that?  Why do you keep coming back to this?  To me it seems like it has already been answered.  What are you trying to achieve?   What is the real decision that you are facing?  What is your motivation here?

Comment: I wonder if you are starting from a faulty premise.  There is not some written list of all policies that ever exist, where those policies have been formally adopted, and where it's permissible to do anything that isn't explicitly forbidden on that list.  That's known as "rules lawyering" and it is discouraged.  On this topic, I suspect that answers to questions here on Meta are the closest we have to policy.